# Add comment meta

Tags: comments, comment-meta

I need to add my custom meta to the new comments. 
Here is what I've done :

```
/************************************************************************/
/*  Add meta to comments
/************************************************************************/
// Save field
add_action ('comment_post', 'add_meta_settings', 1);

function add_meta_settings($comment_id) {
    add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'comment_section', $_POST['comment_section'], true);
}
```

This work when I create a new comment. But if I post a comment using the "Reply" (to another comment) link, the meta is not saved...

After further investigation :

On the same page, I have 3 comment threads. Each comment has a meta that tells in which tread they have to be displayed in. At the end of each thread, I have a form to post a comment in this specific thread and it adds the right meta.

The problem is when I click the “Reply” link, it adds a form under the comment, but not the good form. It adds the first form that appears in the page, event if I reply a comment from the third thread. So the meta that is added with my new comment is not the good one…

Is there a way to tell WordPress which form to use when I click the “Reply” link ?

Could you help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: `add_comment_meta` returns a true/false success value, but you're not checking this, can you find out what it returns when you attempt to reply?

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell ! I've edited my question with further investigation :) ! Thanks

Comment: hmm I'm of the opinion **we still require more technical information**, such as the value of the `$_POST['comment_section']` variable when trying to make a comment via reply, and the return value of `add_comment_meta` indicating true or false. I suspect it's because hitting reply sends via AJAX and you're trying to save an empty value, but without further information I cannot diagnose the issue further or verify this.

Comment: If I inspect the html generated in the reply comment, the hidden field containing the value of "comment_section" has always the value of the meat of the first comment form appearing in the page : "comments".

Comment: hmmm but what do those variables I enquired about contain? If you don't know how to get that you can just ask =]

Comment: If I switch the first and the second thread, the value of the "comment_section" in the reply form will always be "labs", which correspond to the new first form. I've check the Database. The meta is save, but always the meta of the first form appearing in the page. So I need to tell wordpress to show a specific reply form for each thread, but how ?

Comment: Its returns true and the $_POST['comment_section'] is always the one of the first form appearing on the page ;)

Comment: are all three comment sections contained within the same form element?

Comment: No, this is separated form element